# How to translate "The mayor has (exactly) two cats" into first-order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

[image: This is what I have so far.]

I'm not sure where 'the mayor' will fit into here.

Comment: This is it already  - provided you define $C(x)$ as "$x$ is a cat owned by the mayor". If you *want* $C(x)$ to stand only for "$x$ is a specimen of *felis catus*" then you need an additional symbol for the ownership relation and a constant symbol for the mayor

Comment: How would I add the constant symbol for the mayor?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I like very much your "felis catus"... Too few latin in Math SE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**
You should include possession of the cats, everywhere you specify what property is being counted.

\begin{equation}\exists x\exists y\big(\big(C(x)\land\color{red}{h(m,x)}\big)\land \big(C(y)\land\color{red}{h(m,y)}\big)\land x\neq y)\land\forall z(\big(C(z)\land \color{red}{h(m,z)}\big)\supset(z=x\lor z=y)\big) \end{equation}

In the above, $h(p,q)$ reads "p has q". I have used the word *has* instead of *owns*, in case the mayor is holding someone else's cats. $h(m,z)$ allows more cats to exist in the world, other than those the mayor has.

For your future reference, I have included the definitions of less than, greater than or equal to, and exactly 1 below this answer.

**Less than n:**

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\forall x_1\dots\forall x_{n-1}\forall x_n((x_1\neq x_2\land\dots\land x_{n-1}\neq x_n)\supset \lnot P(x_1)\lor\dots\lor\lnot P(x_{n-1})\lor\lnot P(x_n))
\end{equation}

**Greater than or equal to n:**

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\exists x_1\dots\exists x_{n-1}\exists x_n(x_1\neq x_2\land\dots\land x_{n-1}\neq x_n\land P(x_1)\land\dots\land P(x_{n-1})\land P(x_n))
\end{equation}

**Exactly 1**

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\exists x(P(x)\land\forall(P(y)\supset y=x))
\end{equation}

Comment: Don't you need to include a "$h(m,z)$" somewhere in the final part of the proposition? As is, it sounds like the proposition is saying "There are exactly two cats in the world, and the mayor has both of them."

Comment: @BarryCipra You are right, thank you.